# Recover the value of a hashmap that is in another hashmap

Tags: java

I want to retrieve the value of key in a Hashmap that is in another Hashmap,

```
static HashMap<String , HashMap<String, Float>> terms = new HashMap(); 
static String date;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException {

         InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(filePath);
         InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
         String ligne;

            while ((ligne=br.readLine())!=null){
              JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
          JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(ligne);
              date =  (String) jsonObject.get("created_at");

              String text =  (String) jsonObject.get("text");
              Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);


              List<String> ss=TokenizewithAnalyzer.tokenizeString(analyzer, text);

              for(String s : ss){
                  ajoutFrequence(s, date);}

              System.out.print("==>"+ss+" \n");}

         for(Entry <String, HashMap<String, Float>> entry : terms.entrySet()){
        // float res=entry.getValue().get(date).floatValue();
         System.out.println(entry.getValue().get(date).floatValue());
           }
         br.close();
           }

    static void ajoutFrequence(String token, String date){
            if(terms.containsKey(token)){
                HashMap<String, Float> freqdate = terms.get(token);
                if(freqdate.containsKey(date)){
                    freqdate.put( date, freqdate.get(date)+1);
                }else{
                    freqdate.put(date, Float.valueOf(1));
                }
            }else{
                HashMap<String, Float> freqdate = new HashMap<>();
                freqdate.put(date, Float.valueOf(1));
                terms.put(token, freqdate);
           } }}
```

in the output I get the frequence in a list for example:
null
null
1.0
null
null
null
I want to do something like this: float freq=entry.getValue().values(); but it is impossible.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do ? You want to print all values of all maps in the entries?

Comment: I need  to get frequence in float type, because later I have to make calculations on this float (multiplication, division).

Comment: you can't cast an array to a float... your 

    entry.getValue().values()

Would return a collections of floats,

Comment: And how to recover this float ?

Answer (score 0):

You use the date as a key in your second map. So I assume you could do following:

```
for(Entry <String, HashMap<String, Float>> entry : terms.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().get(date));
 }
```

To access a specific value in your second map, you need to provide a key for this value. In your case, this key is a date.

Comment: I have null everywhere.

Comment: @celia where do you have a null? what is the purpose of using date as key in your second map?

Comment: I get null in the output . I declared date as a global variable because it does not recognize it.

Comment: You need to use the same date that you used in "ajoutFrequence(s, date);"

Comment: I get this 1.0
null
null
null

Comment: Please post your full programm, from those pieces it is not clear what you are doing

Comment: @celia can you please then clarify what is expected output?

Comment: I want to eliminate a stop words using lucene and i have used "Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);", but it doesn't eliminate all stop words, for this i want to use Porteranalyzer but i don't know how use it ?, can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in fact I used two loop to traverse the hashmap and I recovered the value of the second hashmap like this:

```
for(Entry <String, HashMap<String, Float>> entry : terms.entrySet()){
                     HashMap<String, Float> d=entry.getValue();
                     for(Entry<String,Float>ent:d.entrySet()){
                     float dd=ent.getValue();
                     System.out.println(dd);}}
```

At the end I got the float. Thank you.